# Display sent emails from Salesforce in VF page

Tags: apex, email, activities

If I've email template sent to lead when it created. Can I display emails sent log inside VF page or should I save any email I sent into object then display them ??

Any idea?

Comment: where do you want to show that email ? on lead detail page ?

Comment: I have custom visualforce page, I thought triggered emails using workflows will be stored into Activity History of Lead. But it didn't @Himanshu

Comment: Your workflow action could also create a completed task under the lead that would record the fact that an email was sent.